# Error index.php not writeable Administrator index.php not writeable In opencart

Tags: vqmod, opencart2.3

i've got problem when i install vqmod in opencart the error say

index.php not writeable

Administrator index.php not writeable

i have no index.php file in my root opencart ,

Admin/index.php

```
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '2.3.0.2');

// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}

// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: ../install/index.php');
    exit;
}
// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');
start('admin');
```

vqmod/install/index.php

```
// CHANGE THIS IF YOU EDIT YOUR ADMIN FOLDER NAME
$admin = 'admin';

// Counters
$changes = 0;
$writes = 0;

// Load class required for installation
require('ugrsr.class.php');

// Get directory two above installation directory
$opencart_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../') . '/';

// Verify path is correct
if(!$opencart_path) die('COULD NOT DETERMINE CORRECT FILE PATH');

$write_errors = array();
if(!is_writeable($opencart_path . 'index.php')) {
    $write_errors[] = 'index.php not writeable';
}
if(!is_writeable($opencart_path . $admin . '/index.php')) {
    $write_errors[] = 'Administrator index.php not writeable';
}

if(!empty($write_errors)) {
    die(implode('<br />', $write_errors));
}

// Create new UGRSR class
$u = new UGRSR($opencart_path);

// remove the # before this to enable debugging info
#$u->debug = true;

// Set file searching to off
$u->file_search = false;

// Attempt upgrade if necessary. Otherwise just continue with normal install
$u->addFile('index.php');
$u->addFile($admin . '/index.php');

$u->addPattern('~\$vqmod->~', 'VQMod::');
$u->addPattern('~\$vqmod = new VQMod\(\);~', 'VQMod::bootup();');

$result = $u->run();

if($result['writes'] > 0) {
    if(file_exists('../mods.cache')) {
        unlink('../mods.cache');
    }
    die('UPGRADE COMPLETE');
}

$u->clearPatterns();
$u->resetFileList();

// Add catalog index files to files to include
$u->addFile('index.php');

// Pattern to add vqmod include
$u->addPattern('~// Startup~', '// VirtualQMOD
require_once(\'./vqmod/vqmod.php\');
VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup');

$result = $u->run();
$writes += $result['writes'];
$changes += $result['changes'];

$u->clearPatterns();
$u->resetFileList();

// Add Admin index file
$u->addFile($admin . '/index.php');

// Pattern to add vqmod include
$u->addPattern('~// Startup~', '//VirtualQMOD
require_once(\'../vqmod/vqmod.php\');
VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup');


$result = $u->run();
$writes += $result['writes'];
$changes += $result['changes'];

$u->addFile('index.php');

// Pattern to run required files through vqmod
$u->addPattern('/require_once\(DIR_SYSTEM \. \'([^\']+)\'\);/', 'require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . \'$1\'));');

// Get number of changes during run
$result = $u->run();
$writes += $result['writes'];
$changes += $result['changes'];

// output result to user
if(!$changes) die('VQMOD ALREADY INSTALLED!');
if($writes != 4) die('ONE OR MORE FILES COULD NOT BE WRITTEN');
die('VQMOD HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON YOUR SYSTEM!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means that you've deleted the file. You might have to reinstall the Opencart or upload the file from default opencart source files. 
Open cPanel File Manager Set permission to 777 for the file

Answer (score 1):

you need to do two things

1)open vqmod/install/index.php

find the following code

```
$admin = 'admin';
```

change its value to your admin folder name that you have changed to

```
$admin = 'youradminfoldername';
```

2)open vqmod/pathReplaces.php

find the following code (if there is no,add it)

```
$replaces[] = array('~^admin\b~', 'xxxxx');
```

change xxxxx to your current admin folder name.

after you have these two things,even if it still show such infomation,
you should be ok to install extension.

I have tested this method ,it works for me.

another solution I guess maybe is to delete vqmod folder and reupload vqmod-opencart-2.6.1，and then only need to modify vqmod/pathReplaces.php,it should works